# Calling functions from other class in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have a class Crypting present in `WEB-INF/classes` in tomcat.
Crypting class has following methods :

`generateKey(w,h)`

`encrypt(key,src)`

`decrypt(key,enc)`

Now I need to access those function in jsp
I have a doubt on how to call them.i.e whether i have to create object for that class and access them or any other method

```
<%@page import="java.io.*,com.Crypting"%>
<%
Crypting c=new Crypting();
img=c.generateKey(w,h);
encr=c.encrypt(img,src);
%>
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is correct , you should have an instance of your class and then call a method from that class , on your code you have to specify type of return in the second line as it was described on your class like !!

```
<%
Crypting c=new Crypting();
img=c.generateKey(w,h); // here specify type of the img object !!
/*Image img = c.generateKey(w,h); for example*/
encr=c.encrypt(img,src); // the same thing here 
%>
```

Comment: what if i use directly classname instead of creating instance of class like this `<% BufferedImage img =Crypting.generateKey(w,h);BufferedImage encr=Crypting.encrypt(img,src);`

Comment: @SKJ in this case your methods should be static to execute at this way , like this `public static BufferedImage generateKey(w,h) `

Comment: OK I understood now .Thanks for your help @PacMan